# I can't install modules in Python

Tags: python, python-module

When I install a module (now it's the `keyboard` module) in the Windows Command Prompt:

```
pip3 install keyboard
```

or

```
python -m pip install keyboard
```

or

```
pip install keyboard
```

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPUEv.png) is the output.
But when I try to import it, I get a [ModuleNotFoundError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXo0S.png).
What is the problem? Could it be a PC space problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What is the directory name shown in the first screenshot? Therefore, which version of Python did you install `keyboard` for? What is the version of Python mentioned by the interpreter in the second screenshot? Do you see why this causes a problem? Also: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Karl just added what I was going to -- anything essential to answering the question (and that includes output logs in this case) should be included **as text** in the question itself.

Comment: From the screenshots it is clear that you install with python 3.10, and try to use it with python 3.9. You have to use the same python executable to install the package that you're intending to use it on.

Comment: The first output shows ``python310`` – Python version 3.10 - but the second shows Python 3.9.

Comment: I used the C: directory, but also C:/Users/Elvis doesn't work

Comment: @np8 Thank you, now it works 

Comment: quick fix would be to find the python executable you are using, inside python shell `import sys; print(sys.executable)` and then use `<python from sys.executable> -m pip install keyboard`.

Comment: As np8 just said.. simplified you are installing the module in the wrong place. Make sure you are in the correct Python (including version) when installing any module. Bonus tip use virtual environments if it's not an isolated system.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy generally I completely agree - you've probably seen my canned comment regarding this - but in this case having the screenshots (particularly of IDLE) was essential to solving the problem. It's doubtful that anyone copying code to paste in a question would include the `sys.version` string at the top. Very interesting conundrum...

Comment: As happens so often, there's no way I could have found the canonical duplicate myself. Thank you @Andras Deak.

Answer (score 0):

You are using different python versions. Please make sure that you are using the same python version.